# Why does the compiler say "Undeclared identifier" for my form's fields?

Tags: delphi

This code gives me an error message: *[Error] Unit1.pas(52): Undeclared identifier: 'Edit1'*.

```
procedure SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(sIPs : String);
begin
  SaveStringToRegistry_LOCAL_MACHINE(
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\' + Edit1.text,
    'NameServer', sIPs);
end;
```

Why do I get this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I rolled this back to the original question you asked (the one that was answered). If you have a new question, ask it as a new question; don't change it entirely after you've received answers. See [What StackOverflow is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133222/172661) for the reasons why this is not how this site works. Thanks.

Comment: In order to answer this question, we need to know where Edit1 is declared, and where the code in the question lives.

Answer (score 7):

Your code isn't a method of the form, and therefore has no access to `Edit1`.

Either make it a form method:

```
type
  TForm1=class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    procedure SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(sIPs : String);
  ...
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(sIPs : String);
 begin
   ...
 end;
```

Or change it to accept the contents of `Edit1.Text` as another parameter:

```
procedure SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(sIPs : String; RegName: String);
begin
  SaveStringToRegistry_LOCAL_MACHINE(
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\' + 
     RegName, 'NameServer', sIPs);
end;
```

And call it like:

```
SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(sTheIPs, Edit1.Text);
```

Comment: You could not WHAT? This solves the problem you posted *exactly*.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the solution that Ken White gave you, for instance if you are not allowed to change the signature of `SetTCPIPDNSAddresses()`, then another option is to access the `TEdit` via the global pointer to its parent `TForm` (if your `TForm` instance is actually making use of that pointer, that is), eg:

```
procedure SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(sIPs : String); 
begin 
  SaveStringToRegistry_LOCAL_MACHINE( 
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\' + Form1.Edit1.Text, 
    'NameServer', sIPs); 
end;
```