# Undeclared identifier: Memo1?

Tags: string, delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undeclared identifier: String variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043392/undeclared-identifier-string-variable)

use of such, error message: [Error] Unit1.pas(51): Undeclared identifier: 'Memo1'

Could you help.

My codes;

```
type
 ....
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure SaveStringToRegistry_LOCAL_MACHINE( sKey, sItem, sVal : string );
var
  reg : TRegIniFile;
begin
  reg := TRegIniFile.Create('');
  reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  reg.WriteString( sKey, sItem, sVal + #0 );
  reg.Free;
end;



procedure SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(sIPs : String);
begin
  SaveStringToRegistry_LOCAL_MACHINE(
  'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\' +
    memo1.text, 'NameServer', sIPs);

end;


procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  Get_AdaptersInfo( memo1.lines );
 end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 SetTCPIPDNSAddresses(Edit1.text+','+ Edit2.Text);
 end;

end.
```

I looking for a method..
How do I make it? I know little english. Sorry. How do I clear the error?

Comment: The problem is exactly the same as in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043392/undeclared-identifier-string-variable). `SetTCPIPDNSAddresses` is not a method of the form, therefore it can't access the memo.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your form has memo1 on it.   adf form1.  in front of the memo1 reference in the settcpipdnsaddresses procedure.